# LINQ to SQL: How to check if any item in one entity collection exists in another entity collection?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm using MVC2 and Entity Framework.

I have 2 Entity Collections and I need to compare them and check if they have any items in common. For example, say I have `EntityCollection<Candidate>` and `EntityCollection<Job>`.  I'm trying to return all candidates that have a skill that is listed in the job's preferred skills.  Is this correct:

```
public IQueryable<Candidate> GetMatchingCandidates(Job job)
{                
     return from candidate in _db.Candidates
     where (candidate.CandidateSkills.Where(c => job.JobPreferredSkills.Any(j => j.SkillId== c.SkillId)).Count() > 0) 
     select candidate;                                
}
```

Similarly, I'd also like to get candidates that have ALL skills that are listed in the preferred skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `Any()` in the first case:

```
    public IQueryable<Candidate> GetMatchingCandidates(Job job)
    {
        return from candidate in _db.Candidates
               where (candidate.CandidateSkills.Any(c => job.JobPreferredSkills.Any(j => j.SkillId == c.SkillId)))
               select candidate;
    }
```

Then use `All()` for your second case (all skills have to be in the preferred skills)

```
    public IQueryable<Candidate> GetMatchingCandidates(Job job)
    {
        return from candidate in _db.Candidates
               where (candidate.CandidateSkills.All(c => job.JobPreferredSkills.Any(j => j.SkillId == c.SkillId)))
               select candidate;
    }
```

Comment: Also, how could I do the one where I want to match on ALL items (in contrast to ANY)?

Comment: @Prabhu: The ALL case was my second example, also note that I replaced your `.Where(...).Count() > 0` in the first case with `Any(..)`

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know they had an All :-)  Yes, I noticed the Any replacement--in fact that's how I had it in the beginning, but changed it for some reason.  So you think this is the right strategy though? The part I wasn't sure about was having a query as an argument to the outer query.

Comment: It looks fine to me, you should check the generated SQL and also do some basic performance testing to see if you need any further optimizations

Comment: I tried this, but am getting this error: : Unable to create a constant value of type 'JobPreferredSkill'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.  Any suggestions? Thanks